# How to zoom to object on WMS layer with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I have a map with WMS layer. And want to zoom to selected object. Now i use `GetCapabilities` from Geoserver and zoom to bbox of whole layer.
So how to do what i want?

Or can u tell me how to get feature bbox from Capabilities? Or how to get FeatureInfo without clicking on map?

**UPDATE**

```
                       info_id=myVecLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",'5')
                       alert(info_id[0].geometry.getBounds());
                       app.mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(info_id[0].geometry.getBounds());
                       //myVecLayer is WFS layer
```

Its do something strange. If feature shows in map window it will be zoomd to it. But if not shows get a error `TypeError: info_id[0] is undefined`. What is wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

Ok now this is Request method

```
                        info_id=OpenLayers.Request.GET({
                                    url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:filedata_temp&featureID=filedata_temp.4',
                                    success: function(e){
                                    alert(e.responseText);
                                    }
                                });
```

its ok. But how to get bbox from there?

**UPDATE 3**

Now i use a GeoExt.FeatureStore to zoom to feature.
But i have a problem i try `zoom_store.layer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",'5');` and all work. But if i use variable `zoom_store.layer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",some_variable);` i get error `TypeError: info_id[0] is undefined`. Why its heppening?

Comment: How did you selected the object in the first place? I guess you already did a WMS GetFeatureInfo or a WFS GetFeaure request to do the selection? Or is the selection just done "visually" with a CQL filter?

Comment: i use CQL filter.

Comment: @Kliver Max, first of all, check out if you have info_id[x] and then run your zooming code...

Comment: I change `getFeaturesByAttribute` to `getFeatureByFid`and all works fine. I dont know whats wrong with `getFeaturesByAttribute` maybe this _Returns an array of features that have the given attribute key set to the given value.  Comparison of attribute values takes care of datatypes, e.g. the string ‘1234’ is not equal to the number 1234._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all i use this.
1. Create GeoExt.FeatureStore.

```
                    zoom_store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
                                layer: myVecLayer,
                                fields: [
                                    {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
                                    {name: 'mydata', type: 'String'}
                                ],
                                 proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
                                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                                        version: "1.0.0",
                                        srsName:"EPSG:900913",
                                        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                                        featureType: "filedata_temp",
                                        featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
                                        //filter:Ffilter
                                    })
                                }),
                                autoLoad: true
                            });
```

2 Create atother one layer.

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable features");
                                app.mapPanel.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
                                vectorLayer.visibility=false;
```

3 Add features to this layer.

```
vectorLayer.addFeatures(some_features);
```

4 Zoom to this layer.

```
app.mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
                            vectorLayer.removeAllFeatures();
```

I will glad if u give me something more usefull.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the bbox you can use the same CQL filter in a WFS GetFeature request, and enable "feature bounding" in the WFS options to make it generate the bbox. This will unfortunately also give you the full feature contents, if you just want the BBOX there is a WPS process that returns just the BBOX instead.

Comment: im update question. And try do request but how parse it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OL enough, but surely there are ways to parse GML? Regardless, if you load the response in a DOM you can just go for the element representing the bounding box of the collection

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solve the problem but you can try this:

zoom_store.layer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",**String(some_variable)**);

Works for me